# Firestore: How to get all documents where a specific field exist

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have a collection in Firestore where some documents contain an array but some don't. The structure looks like this:

```
document1 = {
    date: '2022-02-02',
    name: 'x',
    array: ['a'],
}   

document2 = {
    date: '2022-02-03',
    name: 'y',
}
```

How can I get all documents where the field `array`exists? So in this example only document1?

Is any of these solutions possible:

```
db.collection('employees').where(`array`, '!=', null).get();
```

```
db.collection('employees').where(`array`, '>=', []).get();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can I get all documents where the field array exists?

When you add data to Firestore make sure to provide a null value for the `array` field like this:

```
document1 = {
    date: '2022-02-02',
    name: 'x',
    array: null,
}
```

In this way, the following query will work perfectly fine:

```
db.collection('employees').where(`array`, '!=', null).get();
```

If it's an ongoing project, and the `array` field doesn't exist at all, then simply update the existing documents with the `array` holding a null value. This is possible because [null is a supported data type in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

Comment: Its an ongoing project. What happens when a document doesnt have the field `array` and I call `db.collection('employees').where(`array`, '!=', null).get();`? Do I get for example the document2 which doesnt have the field `array`?

Comment: No, you won't, since document2 doesn't contain an `array` field that holds the value of null. So those documents will **not** be returned. So you have to update the rest of the documents to have an array field with null. Remember, holding a null value it's doesn't mean that the field doesn't exist.

Comment: bro I wanna do the same but I wanna pass the Id of the colluction

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should try your solutions.

If they dont work, you can try to loop through your documents and check if `doc.data().array` exists

Answer (score 0):

Use OrderBY to get the doc if field exists

```
 firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("missions")
  .orderBy("quote", "asc")
  .get();
```