# How to query field exist some document in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I using firebase, nodejs and i have a question how to query field exist some document.

Example :

```
  Collections : users => document : A with field {
                                                    ....
                                                    is_correct: true
                                                   }
                          document : B with field {
                                                   .....
                                                  }
```

In my above example , i have two document in collection users. On document **A** i have field **is_correct: true** and on document **B** field **is_correct** not exist.
My collection users about 15.000 document and it have 50 document contain field **is_correct: true**

When i write code look like :

```
await firestore.collection('users').where('is_correct', '==', true).get();
```

it can get correct me 50 document. But i don't understand it can using index on field is_correct or not ? And it can query best performance ?  I understand firebase can't get document if field undefined. It impart in case ? Please help ? Thanks you

Comment: I think that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71144596/firestore-how-to-get-all-documents-where-a-specific-field-exist/71144734#71144734) might also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple query like

```
firestore.collection('users').where('is_correct', '==', true)
```

you don't need to configure any index, Firestore does it automatically.

---

As you mentioned, only documents **where the given field exists** can match the query.

And this is the case also for Not-equal (`!=`) and `not-in` queries: they exclude documents where the given field does not exist, as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not_equal_).

Also, note that a field exists when it's set to any value, including an empty string (`""`), `null`, and `NaN` (not a number).

---

So, in conclusion, if you want to query for documents where `is_correct` is not `true`, you need to create this field in these documents with a value different than `true`.

Comment: if i understand correctly, will firestore use the index to retrieve my 50 documents or does firestore have to scan all 15,000 documents and get the document i want. In my case I just want to get the fields where is_correct equals true. Documents without is_correct field equal to true will not affect anything.  It right ?

Comment: Firstore uses the index to find the 50 document. You'll only pay the reads for the documents matching the query. You'll find some very clear explanations about this process in this [official video](https://youtu.be/Ofux_4c94FI?t=331) (Note that at the time the video was published, the not-in queries where not available). "Documents without is_correct field equal to true will not affect anything." => That's right.