# Firestore, should we avoid using value type null?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

According to [Firestore supported data type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types):

1. `undefined` is not a supported data type
2. `null` is a supported data type

However, according to [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in):

[image]

so since we cannot do `x != null`(I think this resulting in a runtime error) and `not-in [...something, null]` match nothing, is there any point using null in Firestore? or we should just avoid it and use the default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that x != null evaluates to undefined. A not-in query with null
> as one of the comparison values does not match any documents.

source https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in

there are 2 statements:

1. x != null evaluates undefined
2. A not-in query with null as one of the comparison values does not match any documents

I examine the statements one by one by running some tests

> 1. x != null evaluates undefined

this statement is false, it works fine, but probably because the sentences is not complete, it should be `x != null evaluates undefined for non-exist field`

> 2. A not-in query with null as one of the comparison values does not match any documents

this statement however, is true

`where("x", "not-in", [null])` and `where("x", "not-in", [...something, null])` will always return empty array even if there is document that fulfil the condition

there is however, a 3rd statement which is missing from the doc

`where("x", "not-in", [...something])` will always exclude doc where `x` is `null`

update I discovered 4th behaviour

when null + 1 data type, eg null + string

> x != something

will include doc where x is null

when there is more than 1 data type, eg null + string + number

> x != something

will not include doc where x is null

update: 5th behaviour

> x in [[{someKey:'someValue'}], [{someKey:'someValue'},{someKey:'someValue2'}], [{someKey:null}], [{someKey:'someValue'},{someKey:null}]]

will include doc where x is `[{someKey:'someValue'}]` and x is

`[{someKey:'someValue'},{someKey:'someValue2'}]`

will not include doc where x is `[{someKey:null}]` and x is

`[{someKey:'someValue'},{someKey:null}]`

meanwhile `array-contains` and `array-contains-any` work normally with `{someKey:null}`

update: 6th behaviour

unlike behaviour 5th, with a similar example (I am aware of the requirement between `in` and `array-contains-any` to be searchable), null works fine with `array-contains` and `array-contains-any`, you can search field in an array that contains null.

null behaviours are too complicated to memorize, I strongly discourage the usage of null

Answer (score 1):

> so since we cannot do x != null

[Yes, we can.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71144596/firestore-how-to-get-all-documents-where-a-specific-field-exist/71144734#71144734)

> I think this results in a runtime error.

No, it doesn't.

> Is there any point using null in Firestore?

Yes, you can query Firestore to get documents that contain a particular field that holds the value of `null`. Obviously, the opposite is available.

**Edit:**

> `not-in` **queries exclude documents where the given field does not exist**.

It makes sense since Firestore queries can only return results based on the existence of a field and not on the absence.

> A field exists when it's set to any value, including an empty string (`""`), `null`, and `NaN` (not a number).

Even if we add an empty string, `null`, or `NaN`, it doesn't mean that the field doesn't exist. It definitely exists and holds one of those values.

> Note that x != null evaluates to undefined. A not-in query with null as one of the comparison values does not match any documents.

That's normal since a value from the list is null. You cannot compare null for non-null values.

Comment: but why the doc says otherwise? What am I missing?

Comment: What are you referring at from the docs?

Comment: i quote from here https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#not-in

Comment: What exactly from there? Please add the exact sentence.

Comment: I updated my question with image

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: I ran some tests and got the answers, I also posted the result in answer, thanks anyway

Comment: I will not marked as answer but I can upvote for your help 

after I ran the tests, my conclusion is I should not use null as value due to how it behaves, I even discover non documented behaviour, see my answer, especially on the 4th behaviour